# Diferencia entre getRootConfigClasses y getServletConfigClasses

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

¿Que diferencia fundamental existe al inicializar las clases de configuración de Spring en **getRootConfigClasses** y **getServletConfigClasses** en la clase **WebInitializer**?

He intentado cambiando la inicializacion de mis clases de configuración en ambos métodos sin resultados diferentes, la teoria dice que son contextos diferentes pero de ambas formas funciona igual.

Me gustaría saber cual es la forma correcta o si representa algún impacto en mi proyecto tenerlo de una forma u otra.

```
    @Configuration
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{SecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class, SwaggerConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
         return new Filter[] {new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain")};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

Así funciona igual por ejemplo:

```
 @Configuration
    public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class,SwaggerConfig.class};
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return new Class<?>[]{};
        }

        @Override
        protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
             return new Filter[] {new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain")};
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[]{"/"};
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `getServletConfigClasses()` devuelve la clase usada para la configuración de la capa web, ejemplo: Controladores, Vistas, etc., mientras que `getRootConfigClasses()` retorna la clase usada para configurar las demás capas de la aplicación, ejemplo: Servicios, Acceso a datos, etc.

[image: configuración spring mvc]

Es posible ubicar toda la configuracion en la clase devuelta por `getRootConfigClasses()`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]